# Update a field based on values from above and below

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a database that looks like this:

```
┌────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ id │ username │  reg_stmp  │
├────┼──────────┼────────────┤
│  1 │ John     │ 1605444385 │
│  2 │ Alice    │            │
│  3 │ Peter    │ 1605962778 │
└────┴──────────┴────────────┘
```

I would like to update the table and fill the missing dates with a value depending on the values above `1605444385` and below `1605962778`
and the outcome should be any number in between and equal (not out of this range).

*Update*

`Mysql version: 5.5`
The rows with empty values could repeat, so the proper value could be many rows above or below. 
There are gaps between the ids.

```
┌────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ id │ username │  reg_stmp  │
├────┼──────────┼────────────┤
│  1 │ John     │ 1605444385 │
│  2 │ Alice    │            │
│  3 │ Paola    │            │
│  6 │ Helen    │            │
│  7 │ Peter    │ 1605962778 │
└────┴──────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: use [LEAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) or [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag)  (it you are using MySQL 8.0+)

Comment: Thank you @Luuk, I updated adding version info.

Comment: How many such records with null date values are there, and in what order should they be updated ? Btw. tag your version such as 5.5, 5.6, 5.7

Comment: Approximately 10.000

Comment: What if the row with a null number is the 1st or the last in the table?

Comment: I mean what number do you want to update the 1st row if it contains a null reg_stmp since there is no previous row?

Comment: With the one below.

Comment: Also are there gaps between the ids?

Comment: Yes. Gaps do exist between ids.

Comment: You men there can be more than 1 missing timestamp between timestamps? If so you should say so in the question..

Comment: You are correct  P.Salmon. I've updated the question some minutes ago. Please refresh.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7 ?

Comment: Yes give me one minute

Comment: The SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5780/1

Comment: So the column to be filled is a date but its data type is VARCHAR and the empty values are not null but `''`?

Comment: you changed a timestamp to a date- was that deliberate?

Comment: No sorry I was in a hurry to fill the values. Its timestamp!

Comment: If it is a timestamp then the empty values must be null although in the definition of the table it is NOT NULL.

Comment: @forpas I just created it on the spot, sorry it has errors.

Comment: Sorry for the errors, havent use fiddle for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LAG replacement but as you can see a LEAD is much more complicated, so i add only 10 seconds to the last known tmiestamp

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `username` VARCHAR(5),
>   `reg_stmp` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table2
>   (`id`, `username`, `reg_stmp`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'John', '1605444385'),
>   ('2', 'Alice', NULL),
>   ('3', 'Peter', '1605962778');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table2 
> INNER JOIN  (select `id`,
> @time := IF (`reg_stmp` IS NULL, @time + 10, `reg_stmp` ) tmptime
>   from table2,(SELECT @time := MIN(`reg_stmp`) FROM table2) a order by `id`
>   ) a1
>   ON table2.id = a1.id
> SET table2.`reg_stmp` = a1.tmptime
> WHERE `reg_stmp` IS NULL
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username |   reg_stmp
> -: | :------- | ---------:
>  1 | John     | 1605444385
>  2 | Alice    | 1605444395
>  3 | Peter    | 1605962778
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e469aadf7cc17b4e57a424a1054c2ed5)*

Comment: Thank you very much nbk, this is more than enough for me. I can change it from here to what I want. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Considering table name is "MT", following query may help u getting ur results for all records

```
Update MT Set Reg_Stmp=Round(Rand()*((Select max(T.reg_stmp) From (Select * From MT) T Where T.ID>MT.ID)-(Select min(T.reg_stmp) From (Select * From MT) T Where T.ID<MT.ID))+(Select min(T.reg_stmp) From (Select * From MT) T Where T.ID<MT.ID),0)
    Where MT.ID<>(Select Min(TT.ID) From (Select * From MT) TT) and MT.ID<>(Select Max(TT.ID) From (Select * From MT) TT)
```

you may change min and max operations based on the requierment.

Comment: Thankjs Nasir, I get "You can't specify target table 'test_tbl' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Check the SQL Fiddle here: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5780/1

Comment: i couldn't understand ur comment. i hv written a simple sql query, do u mean the solution has a problem??

Comment: Nasir I just tested it in the link I wrote in the above comment and gave that error.

Comment: but the example u are tested upon has a different data

Comment: I changed MT to test_tbl and tested your query here: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5780/1
and I got that error I told you.

Comment: I created a fiddle after in order to test your query the names may differ from the real one. I created it in order just to check your query and you can test it too.

Comment: i hv tested and run the query and found it ok now